# Cardinality of set-Discrete math

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Take $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,5\}$.

If we unionized them together it would be $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,5\}$ and if we intersected them it would be $A\cap B=\{1,2\}$.

However, if we change $B$ to $B=\{\{1,2\},2,5\}$ would a set within a set change the previous answers and why?

Comment: Yes, it would; do you have any idea how?

Comment: Unfortunately not, do you know? And if so could you please explain why?

Comment: Side remark: Fortunalety, you wrote $\{\{1,2\},2,5\}$ and not $\{\{1,2\},2,3\}$ as this would have initiated a discussion whether or not $\{1,2\}=3$. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it changes the union and intersection. We now have

$$A\cup B=\{1,2,3\}\cup\big\{\{1,2\},2,5\big\}=\big\{1,2,3,\{1,2\},5\big\}$$

and

$$A\cap B=\{1,2,3\}\cap\big\{\{1,2\},2,5\big\}=\{2\}\;.$$

The set $\{1,2\}$ is an object in its own right, distinct from the objects $1$ and $2$; $1$ and $2$ are elements of $A$, and $\{1,2\}$ is now an element of $B$, so these three distinct objects are all elements of the union $A\cup B$, along with the other elements of $A$ and $B$.

$1$ is now an element of an element of $B$, but it is not itself an element of $B$. Thus, the only object that $A$ and $B$ now have in common is $2$, and the intersection is therefore $\{2\}$.